# How to permanently deploy my own personal app on my iOS device?

Tags: ios

I know how to develop and deploy iOS apps to my iPhone / iPad, with the free developper (based on AppleID) account. The problem is that they only last for 7 days and need to be redeployed afterwards.

What is the best option to develop a personal app and have it permanently installed? I read you need to pay the $99/year developper fee. If so, how does it work: how do I deploy the app on the App Store but restrict its visibility / access to me only?

Any alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: When you pay the developer fee you are not required to publish in AppStore, you can use other mean of app déploiement as adhoc distribution or TestFlight l (validity of app is limited to 3 months for the latter)

Comment: Do you have a link that I could follow to understand what other means of deployments would be available to me? (Crazy I'd need to pay an annual fee to use my own developed app on my own phone, but he!)